# What is the simplest way to backup a large (Aperture) photo library automatically to a different physical location (presumably through the cloud)?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, backup, iphoto, aperture

I have about 10k pictures, (close to 50GB) on my MacBook Pro, all stored in an Aperture Library.

I run time machine (on Snow Leopard if it matters), so they're backed up hourly to my time capsule, plus I burn DVDs annually.   But we had a fire scare recently, and it reminded me that both the DVDs and the Capsule are in the same physical location as the laptop, making them useless if the apartment getting destroyed is the problem (rather than the drive failure I was focused on originally).

I can obviously store the DVDs in a location outside the house, but really don't want to risk a year's data, and it's too annoying to burn all those disks monthly, etc.

Is there an automatic solution that will back up this much data automatically somewhere offsite?   I'm willing to pay something in theory, but the paid idisk solution on MobileMe doesn't seem scalable, and I don't trust its longevity.  Ideally, I want something I don't have to run myself periodically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to pay you can also go with [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/). They have 50GB for $100 a year. I love how fast they synch.

Comment: After hearing multiple reference to dropbox, I installed it last night. The conceptual and functional models are particularly minimal and elegant. The cross-platform "just works" factor was impressive. Disclosure: no connection, etc., etc., I don't even know what continent they're on.

Answer (score 1):

Try jungle disk https://www.jungledisk.com/personal/ it backs up to amazon and/or rackspace cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Carbonite or Mozy.  I have used Mozy on a PC and Mac and have >1TB backed up offsite for $5 a month.

Answer (score 1):

Many people carry their laptops regularly between home and work. In those cases there is a very simple off-site backup solution: Just buy another external hard drive and keep it in your office. Whenever you are at work, plug it in and use it for backups. This way you will have full up-to-date backups in two different physical locations.